# ruby thrift serialization compression

Tags: ruby, serialization, thrift

I am using the thrift ruby gem and am doing the following

```
serializer = Thrift::Serializer.new()
binary_string=serializer.serialize(my_thrift_obj)
```

and I am storing this binary_string in a file, but I noticed there is no compression at all. Is there any way I can compress my_thrift_obj while serializing?

Also, is there a way to serialize arbitrary ruby hashes to thrift objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following reply from the thrift author Mark Slee.

> The compact protocol doesn't do compression, the word compact refers
>   to the way it encodes structure and type metadata.
>
> Thrift is intended for strongly-typed structured data serialization,
>   not compression. A file is already serialized - it sounds like what
>   you really want is to compress serialized data. Would recommend using
>   zlib or gzip for that.